# Parsing Web Page Using Python 3.x and Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, html, parsing, python-3.3

I'm trying to parse this [web-page](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Card_Tips%3aBlue-Eyes_White_Dragon) by the categories of the headers (Searchable By, Special Summoned from Hand by, etc) I've looked around for a good parser for 3.3 but all I could find was BeautifulSoup (which I can't install because it's still coded in 2.x) and lxml which I can't understand. I try reading the HTML itself and searching the code for the headers but to no avail. Can anyone help me?

Comment: According to the docs: `Beautiful Soup 4 works on both Python 2 (2.6+) and Python 3.`

Comment: No I've installed it and all the code is written in 2. I've even asked around and a lot are having the same problem.

Comment: @user1985351: What version of BeautifulSoup? There are two versions (3 and 4). Also, Wikia has an API: http://api.wikia.com/wiki/Wikia_API_Wiki

Answer (score 1):

Actually you could use Beautiful Soup for Python 3.x. [Beautiful Soup homepage](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) says:

```
Beautiful Soup 4 works on both Python 2 (2.6+) and Python 3.

Beautiful Soup is licensed under the MIT license, so you can also download the 
tarball, drop the bs4/ directory into almost any Python application (or into 
your library path) and start using it immediately. (If you want to do this under 
Python 3, you will need to manually convert the code using 2to3.)
```

If you need help on how to manually convert Python 2 code to Python 3, refer to [Converting BeautifulSoup 4 for Python 3](http://annelagang.blogspot.com/2012/11/beautifulsoup-4-for-python-3x.html) for instructions. HTH.